# Battery Issue with Ubuntu 18.04 on lenovo X1 carbon (6th gen)

Tags: 18.04, hardware, battery

So I have bought an X1 carbon a week ago. Immediately changed the SSD and installed ubuntu 18.04. A week later, today, I cannot boot the machine unless I am plugged into the power adapter. I can charge the laptop for about two hours but the moment I remove the charger the laptop immediately shuts down (not in a normal fasion) just like a desktop that has its power cord removed while running. Any ideas on how to solve this? Is this an issue with ubuntu or completely a hardware issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried completely removing the battery while it's unplugged.....pressing the start button with the battery still out, then re installing the battery and powering up?

If it's an issue with ubuntu, you should still get something to flash on the screen such as BIOS messages.  Otherwise, check the user guide for how to disable quick boot then try again.

If none of that helps just try to power it up on just the battery.   If nothing at all...no clicks, no whirring sound at all, I would suspect there's a problem with the battery.

Comment: No absolutely nothing flashing or reacting when I press the power button. I'll try to remove the battery. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: You're welcome.  Hope it helps.  If so please consider up voting my assistance.

Comment: I am a new user, even if I try to vote you up it doesn't show.

Comment: **@r.a** You can also [accept](/help/accepted-answer) an answer...  **User6655** Upvoted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

#### The simple solution:

- If removing the charger cuts off power ⇨  the battery is dead ⇨  **Warranty case.**

Comment: That is what the other (upvoted) answer already said...

Comment: The other answer tries a different and longer approach – 1. removing the battery and trying to reset the hardware by pressing the power button; 2. starting with battery only. My approach clarifies the question of whether the battery is defective in one simple step. Unplug and see.

Comment: Thank you, asked at a repair shop and they said the same

Comment: **linrunner**: please see my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1091177/revisions) Clearer now and an upvote...  **;-)**